# Adding multiple values in php Solr

Tags: php, solr

How would I go about adding multiple values to a multiValued field using the php solr extension?

Comment: Isn't it just comma-delimited?

Answer (score 8):

You would simply iterate the array (multiValued),
and run addField once for each of the array value.

```
foreach (array('Justin', 'Sean') as $coder)
{
  $doc->addField('coder', $coder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works - I thought I tried this, but I actually mistyped something.

Comment: +1 . Kint make sure you click the check mark next to the answers that work for you. For help, read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Wow the docs on this module are lacking.  http://php.net/manual/en/solrdocument.addfield.php

Comment: ajreal - Thanks.  That's a more versatile way of doing it.
Frank - You can always add a comment to the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 2):

### First:

Add a multivalued field in your solr instance, and restart it.

### Second:

```
<?php
$multi_values = array("val-1", "val-2", "val-3");
foreach ($multi_values as $i => $value) {
    $SolrInputDocument->addField("field_name", $value, $i);
}
```

### Its work!

view [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/solrinputdocument.addfield.php) here